# Is there interphase between meiosis I and meiosis II?

Tags: meiosis, cell-cycle

Is there interphase between meiosis I and meiosis II? 
After 2 haploid cells are formed in meiosis I, do the cells go through a period of interphase (G1, S, G2) or do they go directly to meiosis II?

Comment: When meiosis starts it is suppose to produce a haploid so because of this there is no need for further replication or growth.

Answer (score 1):

The technical name of this brief "interphase" between meiosis I and meiosis II is *[interkinesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interkinesis)*.

Interkinesis is normally short (it may not even happen) and it's not divided in G1, S or G2, mainly because there is no DNA duplication, which defines the S (Synthesis) phase.

Source: [A Glossary of Genetics and Cytogenetics: Classical and Molecular](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=iGzmCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA277&dq=interkynesis&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=interkynesis&f=false)

Comment: spelling edit suggested. Interk**y**nesis --> interk**i**nesis.

Answer (score 0):

Telophase I, is followed by an interphase, called **interkinesis**, similar
to the mitotic interphase.

During interkinesis the chromatin is partially uncoiled; however, there is no replication of the genetic material, because each chromosome already consists of two chromatids.

Furthermore, the sister chromatids in interkinesis are generally not genetically identical, because crossing over in prophase I has reshuffled genetic material
between the maternal and paternal chromosomes (i.e recombination).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Concepts of Genetics by Klug and Cummings; ed 7](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=WKBWRbvG_w8C&lpg=PA65&ots=1B8CSmKabf&dq=in%20many%20organisms%2C%20telophase%201%20reveals%20a%20nuclear%20membrane%20forming%20around%20the%20dyads.%20Next%2C%20the%20nucleus%20enters%20into%20a%20short%20interphase%20period.%20In%20other%20cases%2C%20the%20cell%20go%20directly%20from%20first%20anaphase%20into%20second%20meioti&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q=in%20many%20organisms,%20telophase%201%20reveals%20a%20nuclear%20membrane%20forming%20around%20the%20dyads.%20Next,%20the%20nucleus%20enters%20into%20a%20short%20interphase%20period.%20In%20other%20cases,%20the%20cell%20go%20directly%20from%20first%20anaphase%20into%20second%20meioti&f=false),

> In many organisms, Telophase 1 reveals a nuclear membrane forming around dyads. Next, the nucleus enters into a short interphase period. *In other cases*, the cells go directly from the first anaphase into the second meiotic division. If an interphase period occurs, the chromosomes do not replicate, since they already consists of two chromatids. In general, meiotic telophase is much shorter than the corresponding step in mitosis.